# adduser to multiple groups

Tags: adduser

I'm trying to add a user into two groups when creating a new account. Now I use this command;

```
adduser --gid 33 --home /home/wwwroot/domain.com --force-badname %USER%
```

and then

```
usermod -a -G group user (let say GID is 1008)
```

I do this for each new user on a webserver to use `SFTP (GID 1008)`.

What i want to do is this:

```
adduser + group + group

adduser --gid 33,1008 --home /home/wwwroot/domain.com --force-badname %USER%
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work this way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with: [usermod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/usermod.8.html), like this:

```
usermod -a -G group1,group2 username
```

Where username is the user you want to modify and group1 and group2 are the new groups you want that user to join. Running the command without the -a argument will remove that user from all groups except group1 and group2.

Comment: thats what im trying to avoid - i want to add the user into 2 groups with the adduser command as is my question

Comment: `useradd -G group1,group2 username` Each group name is separated by a comma, with no intervening spaces.